# Slim 3.0 is not working with php-fpm 7 and nginx. Return 404

Tags: php, nginx, slim, centos7

I have set up a Slim application on Centos 7 with php-fpm 7 and SlimFramework 3.0, nginx. Here is my config:

```
    location /projects/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        rewrite index.php/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 last;
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php{
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

and

```
upstream php-fpm {
        #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
```

However it is not working and returns 404 for any routes. My test route is:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/cc', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->write("dcmmm");
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: check your location `root /var/www/html;` i think this should look somethink like this `root /var/www/html/Slim`

Comment: that's the common root for all php codes on my server, so Slim codes are under /var/www/html/projects/slim_api